# I have a custom control based on TextBox, but the Text doesn't change in the TextChanged handler

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here's my custom control, with the custom xaml style:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyControls
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
    }
}

<Style TargetType="controls:CustomTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:CustomTextBox">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="" />
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And when used, the `TextChanged` handler doesn't get an updated `Text` field for some reason.

```
<controls:CustomTextBox x:Name="ControlInstance"
                        TextChanged="OnTextChanged"
                        InputScope="EmailNameOrAddress" />

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ControlInstance.Text is always ""!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're changing the `Text` property of the inner TextBox in your template, but not the `Text` property of your CustomTextBox itself.

I recommend you check out http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-wp7-custom-control-in-7-steps for help in creating your custom control.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought I was inheriting the `Text` property from `TextBox`.

Comment: You are. But you put a *second* TextBox inside your template and bound the Text property to the inner TextBox.

Comment: Hi Paul! Thanks for the hint. I had the same problem.